# Manipulating pivot tables filters with python

Tags: python, filter, pivot

I have a report that contains a pivot table in it and I want to filter that pivot table (filter values are not in the table) and then copy that data and paste it in another file. I tried using the source data table but that comes from a restricted Sharepoint in my company so I cannot access that table. I want the table to show values for `AREA = 1` and `ZONE = 3`

I tried using pandas but everything I found to do this applies if you create the pivot table from scratch

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example, what you've tried, the error you're facing and the expected output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.